# C# Instalador - Registros de windows

Tags: c#

Estoy generando un **instalador de aplicación windows form** en visual studio, pero lo que busco es que al instalar la aplicación en la computadora se den de alta algunos **registros de windows (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT)** en el equipo, alguien sabe si esto es posible hacerlo desde el instalador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo personalmente hago esto agregando a la solución un proyecto tipo "setup project" que esta en la categoría "otro tipo de proyectos/Visual studio installer", si no esta lo debe agregar.

Con un proyecto de este tipo puede crear su propio instalador personalizado que verifique prerequisitos de software, pantallas personalizables , iconos en menú inicio, escritorio etc, ajustes del registro, etc